# SQL Server 2017 filestream failing for application after Windows OS upgrade

Tags: sql-server, filestream

After upgrading one of our database servers (with SQL Server 2017) from Windows Server 2016 to 2019 the filestream functionality started to fail. The applications gets

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The request is not supported

for OpenSqlFileStream. The application server is using Windows Server 2019 so both are now using the same OS version.

We have rebooted both the application and the database server. Still failing. We have logged into the application server and started a PowerShell as the service user (running the application as a service) and have no problems with listing files in the network shared MSSQLSERVER folder (made available by the SQL Server). So it doesn't seem to be an access problem.

Anyone recognizing this?

Comment: Do you have full read/write access from the remote client under the username of the client?

Comment: Yes, the service account can read/write files in the filestream folder via Powershell commands.

Comment: It seems like I've been a bit misinformed by the testers. Storing a new report fails in a certain situation and not in general in our acceptance environment. Although strange that the same application version and the same database data works fine in the production environment where the database server still uses Windows 2016. It's almost like some OS functionality related to Win32 has changed in Windows 2019.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the service account. When you access the files you are accessing them using the client credentials, the same as if you were on the client PC and browsed to `\\myserver\myshare\filestream_folder` in Windows Explorer

Comment: I personally can browse the filestream folder with my credentials. In our case a job within the service application fails when trying to create a new file in the filestream so the operation is using the credentials of the service account.

Comment: It turns out that we try to create the file with read/write access. When changing to write only access it works. Strange that it works fine for the databaser server running on Win 2016. Even stranger is that also works fine on a Win 2019 test server where the application and database service is co-located using the same versions as in failing environment.